# Add paragraph based on tag (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, tags, conditional-statements

I want to append a disclaimer paragraph to my single posts based on a tag, specifically my "affiliate" tag. I have tried a few codes I found online that show some text but cause my excerpt to be blank. I don't have as much PHP knowledge as I'd like, if someone could point me in the right direction to writing a function for this.

Comment: Please post some example code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a function for this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag

This should work:

```
<?php if ( has_tag('affiliate') ) { ?>
    <p>Disclaimer paragraph</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something to put in my functions.php but I didn't even think about adding something like this to my single.php. Now I feel silly!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code, it's appearing after my social share buttons.. but oh well.

`function affiliate_add_to_content( $content ) {

```
if( is_single() ) {

  if (has_tag('affiliate')) {
```

$content .= 'The disclaimer here';
}

```
}

return $content;
```

}
add_filter('the_content', 'affiliate_add_to_content');`